# Removing switches from 4 way switch

Tags: electrical

We have a situation like the following image:

[image]

The only difference is the wire on the far right switch going from the switch up to the light is red instead of black.

All of those switches are powered and control each other but don't control an actual light. My thought is one of the two main living lights may previously had been a fan or something that are no longer there.

The switch in the far right of the image we want to put an insteon scene switch. The top left button would be the on and off for the switch which wouldn't actually control anything, but the 7 other buttons we could program to control scenes in the house.

We want to remove the other 2 switches that are part of the 4 way. If we just cap them all off, then the one on the far right won't be powered up and wouldn't work.

To note, the two we want to remove are each part of gang boxes with other switches so the cables would still be fully accessible later on by taking the switch face plate off for future owners.

So what we did was the middle switch in the image, attached red to red and black to black. That works. For the other switch (far left in image), not sure what we need to do, cap the all off? Attached certain wires to each other?

Comment: Can you provide a photo of the inside of the far right box in particular?

Comment: Hi again! Thanks for helping out with this other separate wiring issue as well. It's a 4 gang box that is crammed full, so would be hard for most to really see what's going on in there. Though the diagram above shows the wires involved with that switch. The only difference as noted is the wire going up is red instead of black. The red and black go down the same tube like  in the photo. If there is a particular wire or bundle youd like more info on though just let me know and can gather that info.

Comment: A good close-up photo with everything pulled out (but not unhooked) should let us trace it out with some patience....

Comment: Can certainly work on that task as a last resort, but as a hypothetical, if wires are identical to diagram above, and a person wanted to cap off the middle and left switch but leave power running to the switch on the right (but doesn't need to be able to actually control a light), which wires would need to be changed? Such as in the middle switch connecting reds to reds and blacks to blacks presumably, but not sure what would need to capped or connected in the far left switch.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have your lefts and rights backwards?  (I.e. you really want to put the Insteon in the diagram's far-*left* box)

Comment: Sorry, not sure where you are reading Insteon would go in far left. In the original question I have, "The switch in the far right of the image we want to put an insteon scene switch." And In that question and in the latest comment mention wanting to remove/cap off the left and middle and that I think I have the middle figured out but haven't figured out the far left yet. So yes, all my above items are correct in regards to left, middle and right.

Comment: Also here is captions for the image above based on my comments above in case that helps? http://i.stack.imgur.com/WYBKv.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the right-hand box -- take the red and black that go to the traveler terminals on the switch, and cap them off.  There will be a likely white wire (hopefully tagged black or red) in that same cable that connects to a black wire -- unhook that nut and cap off the white wire.  This disconnects the switch loop entirely.  Then wire the black that was connected to the likely-white (maybe tagged) wire to the line terminal on the Insteon switch.  From there, you can remove the wire from the common terminal on the switch and connect it to the load terminal on the Insteon switch, and connect the neutral terminal on the Insteon switch to the neutral bundle in the box (with a white pigtail if need be).  Ground the Insteon switch, and put everything back together in this box.

The center box can be left as-is.  In the left box, your job is simple -- take the wires off the existing switch and cap them all individually.

Comment: Will check this out today.